# how to get size of docker image layers

Tags: docker

I have pulled a couple of images from my private repo. am able to see the size of the layers using `docker history <image-id>` i don't see actual layer sha256 id for the layers instead it shows missing. So am not sure how I can get the size of each layer.

Actually, I want the size of each layer in the image.

am able to get layers details from docker-inspect command `docker inspect <image-id> | jq .[].RootFS.Layers`

```
docker history f183414e30ab
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
f183414e30ab        16 months ago       /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   317MB
<missing>           16 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B
<missing>           16 months ago       /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /run/systemd && echo 'do…   7B
<missing>           16 months ago       /bin/sh -c set -xe   && echo '#!/bin/sh' > /…   745B
<missing>           16 months ago       /bin/sh -c [ -z "$(apt-get indextargets)" ]     987kB
<missing>           16 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:3ddd02d976792b6c6…   63.2MB
```

Problem trying to solve: am trying to get the size of docker image layers which also been shared with other images.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for command [docker system df](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/)

Comment: Thanks, Sandeep. I think i got it. i can use `docker system df -v` it will show the shared and unique usage for images but i looking more on the image shared layer size. 

For example:

Image A and B 
A total size reported 8 GB.  layer 3  from image A is shared with image B 
B total size reported 8 GB 
layer 3 size is 2GB. but am actuall looking for disk usage of shared layers